# How to Manipulate List to String and print in seperate row

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to export the 4 columns with the below code.the last column organization is a List.

```
    String appname = "abc";
    String path = "//home/exportfile//";
    String filename = path + "ApplicationExport-" + appname + ".txt";
    String ret = "false";

    QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();
    Filter[] filters = new Filter[1];
    filters[0] = Filter.eq("application.name", appname);
    ops.add(filters);

    List props = new ArrayList();
    props.add("identity.name");

    // Do search
    Iterator it = context.search(Link.class, ops, props);

    // Build file and export header row
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
    out.write("IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization");
    out.newLine();

    // Iterate Search Results
    if (it != null) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            // Get link and create object
            Object[] record = it.next();
            String identityName = (String) record[0];
            Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

            // Get Identity attributes for export
            String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");

            // Get application attributes for export
            String userid = "";

            List links = user.getLinks();
            if (links != null) {
                Iterator lit = links.iterator();
                while (lit.hasNext()) {
                    Link l = lit.next();
                    String lname = l.getApplicationName();
                    if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname)) {
                        userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                        List organizations = l.getAttribute("Organization");

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String listItemsSeparator = ",";

                        for (Object organization : organizations) {
                            sb.append(organization.toString());
                            sb.append(listItemsSeparator);
                        }

                        org = sb.toString().trim();

                    }
                }
            }

            // Output file
            out.write(identityName + "," + userid + "," + workforceid + "," + org);
            out.newLine();
            out.flush();
        }

        ret = "true";
    }

    // Close file and return
    out.close();
    return ret;
```

the output of the above code will be.for ex:

```
IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization

dthomas,dthomas001,12345,Finance,HR
```

How do i get the output in below fashion

```
IdentityName,UserName,WorkforceID,Organization

dthomas,dthomas001,12345,Finance

dthomas,dthomas001,12345,HR
```

what and where i need to change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write one line to the file *for each* organization. So, basically, do not concatenate all organizations for a user with the string builder and move the output statements into the for loop that iterates through the organizations.

But it's difficult to provide a working example, because you're code you've shown doesn't compile yet...

---

This should bring you somewhat closer to the solution:

```
if (links != null) {
  Iterator lit = links.iterator();
  while (lit.hasNext()) {
    Link l = lit.next();
    String lname = l.getApplicationName();
    if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname)) {
      userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
      List organizations = l.getAttribute("Organization");
      for (Object organization : organizations) {
        // Output file
        out.write(identityName + "," + userid + "," + workforceid + "," + organization);
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried removed stringbuilder and do the For loop for the output .but didnt got any help..

Answer (score 0):

*Remove* this innermost `for` block and associated variables:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Object organization : organizations)
{
    sb.append(organization.toString());
    sb.append(listItemsSeparator);
}

org = sb.toString().trim();
```

*Move* the declaration of `organizations` *outside* the `if (it != null) {` block:

```
// Get application attributes for export
String userid = "";
List organizations = null;
List links = user.getLinks();

if (it != null)
{
    Iterator lit = links.iterator();
    while (lit.hasNext())
    {
        Link l = lit.next();
        String lname = l.getApplicationName();
        if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
        {
            userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
            organizations = l.getAttribute("Organization");
```

And then change this file output code:

```
// Output file
out.write(identityName + "," + userid + "," + workforceid + "," + org);
out.newLine();
```

To this:

```
// Output file
for (Object organization : organizations)
{
    out.write(identityName + "," + userid + "," + workforceid + "," + organization.toString());
    out.newLine();
}
```

Comment: i tried that option earlier.But i was stuck with the below error:
java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : Can't iterate over type: class bsh.Primitive : at Line: 81 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.io.File; import java.io.B . . . '' : for ( Object organization : organizations )